# Why we have to remove location listener in FusedLocationProviderClient?

Tags: fusedlocationproviderclient

I had a problem in which the location callback wasn't refreshing. So I added `mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates().`

Why do we have to remove the location callback? Shouldn't It update itself whenever I move to a new location?

In the docs it stated this as:

> This call will keep the Google Play services connection active, so
> make sure to call removeLocationUpdates(LocationCallback) when you no
> longer need it, otherwise you lose the benefits of the automatic
> connection management.

Can someone explain this?